# Beginner Android - method to use variables or files across different activities?

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, global-variables

I am writing a simple application and trying to come up with the best (most simple) approach to what I am trying to do.

Basically it is a simple train management application. One part of this will be keeping track of the cars on the train and also the number of open/occupied seats on each individual wagon.

I thought one approach would be to just have a two arrays. One integer array that holds the number of seats in a wagon. This way I can pop off the last element when a ticket is purchased and always have the correct number. The other array would just hold these int arrays representing the individual wagons. 
The other approach I considered would be to store and pull the info from a text file. I would think that the first approach would be easier.

So two questions - 1) Is there another approach that I am missing?
2) (the real question) How can I manipulate/access the arrays between different Android activities. One activity lists the wagons, while another lists the seats, and yet another allows a ticket to be purchased, requiring me to remove an element from the array.

Sorry for the length and thank you for any help.

Comment: I should also mention that I don't care what happens to the values when the application is shut down, I just need the values to be accessed and updated from different activities across the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways for sharing data between activities:

- SharedPreferences, where you store your data in key/value pairs (check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref))
- use internal storage and save your data in the file; you'd have to write methods to write/load your arrays to/from the file
- use SQLite database - check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

The above are from a guide on android.com, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) out and choose what fits your program.

Comment: If you are keeping this app really simple, then any of the above would work fine. If you're going to be managing lots of trains and schedules, you're going to wind up using SQLite.

Comment: also if you have constant data, you may use res/values/string.xml

Comment: Am I able to pass arrays through SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1):

One way is when changing activities you pass a bundle with your arrayList or array like:

```
    Intent newActivity = new Intent();
    newActivity.putArray(List)Extra(yourArray);
    startActivity(newActivity);
```

You can also start your activity for result if you need to pass data back to your first activity. Persistent data is used with SharedPreferences if you need to store information when your for example exiting your app

Edit: In second Activity:

```
    int[] passedArray = getIntent.getIntArrayExtra();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an application class and put your data there in static variables (or use getters and setters).