# how to use the same ImageView in 2 diffent activities?

Tags: java, android, android-view

i am beginner i need help PLEASE
i have an Image View in first_activity and i set it to **View.GONE** this is the first value and then in my second_activity i have ***if statement*** if the condition is true the Image View in first_activity will be **View.VISIBLE**

```
public static ImageView [] sol = new ImageView[20] ;
  sol[0]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol1) ;
        sol[1]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol2) ;
        sol[2]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol3) ;
        sol[3]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol4) ;
        sol[4]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol5) ;
        sol[5]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol6) ;
        sol[6]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol7) ;
        sol[7]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol8) ;
        sol[8]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol9) ;
        sol[9]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol10) ;
        sol[10]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol11) ;
        sol[11]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol12) ;
        sol[12]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol13) ;
        sol[13]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol14) ;
        sol[14]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol15) ;
        sol[15]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol16) ;
        sol[16]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol17) ;
        sol[17]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol18) ;
        sol[18]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol19) ;
        sol[19]=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol20) ;
        for(int i=0;i<sol.length;i++) {
            sol[i].setVisibility (View.GONE);
        }
```

i wonder how to use it in both activities

Comment: i think it's more cleaner if you declare your array as such `ImageView [] sol = new ImageView[] {(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol1), (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.sol2)[,...]};` but that's just my opinion ;)

Comment: and how about the problem  how to access the imageview from second activity to make it VISIBLE

Comment: you mean that want to pass some info from second_activity to first_activity?

Comment: If so, an intent can hold values. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Comment: bro i don't want to pass a value i want to use the same imageview to control it by set it to gone and visible that's all it's always gone unless some condition become true in second activity

Comment: Activity is not designed to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547369/beginner-android-method-to-use-variables-or-files-across-different-activities

Comment: You can't use the same `ImageView` on two different activities, but you can use the same `Image` per se. By using image caching and loading the image separately in each activity you could get a pretty much seamless transition in that sense. Or maybe explain a little more about what is it that you're trying to accomplish.